# Angular pagination table with ngrx/store

Tags: angular, pagination, ngrx-store

I am using Angular 8 with ngrx store. I have no idea how to implement pagination on my existing code. I would like to use ngb-pagination if is possible, if is not please give me some solution, take a look on examples. I saw few examples of adding pagination but they are without nrgx store, for me it's necessary to be included in my project.

fetch-component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Contacts } from 'src/app/models/contacts';
import { Store, select } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AppState } from '../state/app.state';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { FetchContacts, DeleteContacts } from 'src/app/state/actions/contacts.actions';
import { getContactss } from 'src/app/state/reducers/contacts.reducer';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fetch-contacts',
  templateUrl: './fetch-contacts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fetch-contacts.component.css']
})
export class FetchContactsComponent implements OnInit {
  loading$: Observable<Boolean>;
  error$: Observable<Error>;


  public contList: Observable<Contacts[]>;

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>, ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  delete(contactsID, contactFirst, contactLast) {
    const ans = confirm('Do you want to delete contact: ' + contactFirst + ' ' + contactLast + '?');
    if (ans) {
      this.store.dispatch(DeleteContacts({ id: contactsID }));
    }
  }

  fetchData() {
    this.store.dispatch(FetchContacts());
    this.contList = this.store.pipe(select(getContactss));
    this.loading$ = this.store.select(store => store.contacts.loading);
  }

}
```

fetch-component.html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<h4>Contact informations: </h4>

<p *ngIf="loading$ | async"><em>Loading... Please wait...</em></p>
<br>
<p>
    <a [routerLink]="['/register-contacts']"><i class="fa fa-address-card"></i> Create New</a>
</p>

<table class='table table-hover'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="display:none!important;">Id:</th>
            <th><i class="fa fa-user"></i> First Name:</th>
            <th><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Last Name:</th>
            <th><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Address:</th>
            <th><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> Telephone:</th>
            <th><i class="fa fa-toggle-on"></i> Actions:</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let cont of contList | async">
            <td style="display:none!important;">{{ cont.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ cont.firstName }}</td>
            <td>{{ cont.lastName }}</td>
            <td>{{ cont.address }}</td>
            <td>{{ cont.telephone }}</td>
            <td>
                <a [routerLink]="['/contacts/edit/', cont.id]"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a> |
                <a [routerLink]="" (click)="delete(cont.id, cont.firstName, cont.lastName)"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between p-2">
    <ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="collectionSize" [(page)]="page" [pageSize]="pageSize">
    </ngb-pagination>
  </div>
</div>
```

contacts-effect.ts:

```
loadContacts$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(FetchContacts),
        switchMap(() =>
            this._contactsService.getContacts().pipe(
                map((contactss) => LoadContactsSuccess({ contactss })),
                catchError(error => of(LoadContactsFailure({ error })))
            )
        )
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

set default page sizes in your component, unless you really want to move that into the store.

```
ngOnInit() {
  .
  .
  .
  this.pageSize = ?;
  this.page = 1;
}
```

Most importantly, unless you want to really handle all this logic in your store I suggest wrapping your table in an ngIf.  This allows you to have the collection ready in your *ngFor and the splicing logic will take care of the displayed content.

```
<div *ngIf="contList | async as contactList">
  <table>
    <tr *ngFor=let cont of contactList " | slice: (page-1) * pageSize : (page-1) 
       pageSize + 
         pageSize">
      <!-- content here -->
    </tr>
  </table>
  ...
  <ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="contactList.length" [(page)]="page" [pageSize]="pageSize">
  </ngb-pagination>
</div>
```

Hope this gets you on the right path.